# How to use opencv on a windows computer saying codec not found

Tags: python, opencv

Hi i am trying to code a program that can detect a color that i am holding over the webcam, then when i move the color the computer should draw a line: i'm following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WQeoO7MI0Bs
my code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


frameWidth = 640
frameHieght = 480
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap.set(3, frameWidth)
cap.set(4, frameHieght)
cap.set(10, 150)

myColors = [[5, 107, 0, 19, 255, 255],  # orange
        [133, 56, 0, 159, 156, 255],  # purple
        [57, 76, 0, 100, 255, 255]]  # green


def findcolor(img, myColors):
    imgSHV = cv2.cvtColor(img)
    lower = np.array(myColors[0][0:3])
    upper = np.array(myColors[0][3:6])
    mask = cv2.inRange(imgSHV, lower, upper)
    cv2.imshow("img", mask)


while True:
    success, img = cap.read()
    findcolor(img, myColors)
    cv2.imshow('Result', img)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
```

On my first laptop it said MFViedeo Format(codec) not found, and on my second laptop it said ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2.cv2'. When i try running the code through jupyter notebook and spyder it says python stopped working.
I also tried the following code just to access my camera but it gives the same ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2.cv2' and python stops working. Here's the code:

```
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BAYER_BG2BGR)
    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xff == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

When i tried the same code on my windows 10 PC it said: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-88911053ec4b> in <module>
     26 while True:
     27     success, img = cap.read()
---> 28     findcolor(img, myColors)
     29     cv2.imshow('Result', img)
     30     if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):

<ipython-input-15-88911053ec4b> in findcolor(img, myColors)
     17 
     18 def findcolor(img, myColors):
---> 19     imgSHV = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BAYER_BG2BGR)
     20     lower = np.array(myColors[0][0:3])
     21     upper = np.array(myColors[0][3:6])
```

error: OpenCV(4.4.0) C:\Users\app_ey*r\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-re_-build-2y91i_7w\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\demosaicing.cpp:1721: error: (-215:Assertion failed) scn == 1 && (dcn == 3 || dcn == 4) in function 'cv::demosaicing'

Comment: Please add the TraceBack (the error message).

Comment: You are missing a parameter to `cvt.Color()`, presumably `cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV` or similar.

Comment: `imgSHV = cv2.cvtColor(img)` should be `imgSHV = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.BGR2HSV)`

Comment: There is no change and i cannot dsend the TraceBack as the output disappears in seconds but i managed to see that it says  "moduleimporterror: no module named cv2.cv2." and python stops working

Comment: Why are you using `COLOR_BAYER_BG2BGR`?

Comment: i tried to use my wired webcam on my first windows 7 computer and it works for few seconds then video pauses. but i do not want to use it on that computer. my other computer says cv2.cv2 not found.